# How to login correctly?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps

I have a login to facebook and if the user is not in my DB then I add him after the login, but If he is already exists I shouldn't do anything.

My question is how should I deal with it?

1. To make one more query to the DB that checks if user exists - before adding it.
2. To let WCF catch it with UpdateException, and throw it to the client.
3. Other option?

My code right now:

```
private async void OnUserInfoChanged(object sender, UserInfoChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DbClient client = new DbClient(); //wcf service

    if (loginButton.CurrentSession != null)
    {
        localSettings.Values["facebookId"] = loginButton.CurrentSession.FacebookId;
        localSettings.Values["UserName"] = loginButton.CurrentUser.Name;

        if (!(await client.IsUserExistsAsync(loginButton.CurrentSession.FacebookId)))
        {
            try
            {
                await client.AddUserAsync(new User() { FacebookId = loginButton.CurrentSession.FacebookId, UserName = loginButton.CurrentUser.Name });
            }
            catch (FaultException<ValidationFault> validationFault)
            {
                Messages.ShowMessage(string.Format("{0}. Details:\n{1}",
                                                         validationFault.Detail.Issue, validationFault.Detail.Details),
                                                        "Validation problem");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Messages.ShowMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

And WCF:

```
public User AddUser(User user)
{
    Validate<User, User.UserMetadata>(user); //Throws fault exception if not valid.

    try
    {
        IUserRepository _user = new UserRepository();
        return _user.Add(user);
    }
    catch (UpdateException ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your code for login.

Comment: Yes, but my main problem is not the code, just the way it should be done...

Comment: And what is your problem? Add to IUserRepository method to check if exists user. And use typed FaultException<UpdateException> to throw it from wcf to client.

Comment: Should I check in the client side if user exists also? or just to add it and catch the UpdateException?

Comment: You should minimize number of requests through WCF (cause every request cost much time). So catch typed FaultException<UpdateException>

Comment: if you use a Azure Mobile Service ?

Comment: Thanks, I will catch it then.